# Python: Class A Creates Instances of Classes B and C, how can B and C call functions in A or each other?

Tags: python, instance

I have three classes that need to be in individual files:
A, B, and C

A creates B and C. Now I need B to be able to tell A that it's time for it to do something with C. How do to this?

In my specific case, I'm using tkinter to create multiple windows and when someone clicks on a button in one window, I want to switch to a different window. However, because python is slow to create the windows in the first place, I'd like to preload them all and just flip between them holding on to any shared information in the screen manager.

I've tried a few things and the solution that seems most promising to me is one where I create yet another object that is the parent of A (say P). Now I can pass A into functions in B and C and then from B and C, I can call functions of A. And because I can import the parent, without worrying about circular imports, I can tell B and C what functions are defined for A. Having trouble figuring out how to tell B and C that A is of type P though the problem there is that there doesn't seem to be a way to cast an object from one class to another.

Any thoughts for how to do that or other better solutions for this problem in general?

Comment: A [mcve] of what you have tried might help illustrate your issue better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize `B` with an instance of class `A` like `self.A`, set that to the instance of `A` that generated this `B` and use it to call your function in `A` that affects `C`. With everything in place your call from the instance of `B` should look like: `self.A.dosomethingwithC()`

Having a sample of your code to toy with would make it easier to explain.

Here is an example of what I meant:

File1.py:

```
from File2 import *
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.myB = B(self)
        self.myC = C()
    def doCthing(self):
        self.myC.go()

someA = A()
someA.myB.doC()
```

File2.py

```
class B():
    def __init__(self,myA):
        self.myA = myA
    def doC(self):
        self.myA.doCthing()
class C():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def go(self):
        print("Made it")
```

Comment: Very nice example, thank you very much Hoog. That is exactly what I'm trying to do.

And I apologize, I forgot an important detail. My issue is that I have roughly 15 classes of B through M or whatever, so I would like to split each one into a separate file. But it appears to me that in that example, A would have to import B and B would have to import A. And Python doesn't like circular imports... Any way to do this?

Comment: So long as whichever class initializes the rest (in this case `A`) imports everything, the rest will not need anything.  Since class `B` doesn't really know what `myA` is it will trust that `myA` has a method called `doCthing()`, only causing issue if you call `doC()` and `myA` does not have this method. I'll split my example into 2 files